# Why does WordPress put "-" (dash) in front of site title

Tags: html, wordpress, meta-tags

I've just noticed that all my WordPress sites render the site title in the following manner...

For a site titled "MySite" in the WordPress dashboard, the html meta tag will be:

```
<title> 
            - MySite    </title>
```

What's with the dash and awkward whitespacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do a copy-and-paste when you entered in your site title?  Try clearing out the title under wp-admin and typing it in manually.

Also, check the theme's template (header.php).

Comment: @Dan- No copy and paste involved.  It happens when you enter a site title from scratch.

Comment: Strange.  Is your theme's template putting the extra whitespace and dash in there?  It should be located in the header.php file.

Comment: @Dan- Wow that's embarrassing- yeah I could've prob checked that.  Could you update your answer w that comment, and I'll mark it right

Answer (score 2):

This is still prevalent in wp... you can use this in fuctions.php to remove the dash, however some mysterious white space will still be there, but you won't have the wacked out &5531; (or whatever is is) rendering in the src html.

```
 /**
 * Remove title whitespace.
 */

  function document_title_separator( $sep ) {
    return "";
  }
  add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'document_title_separator', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This should be the answer.